# Android Google maps api vs JavaScript Google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What would be the advantages/disadvantages of including Google maps in an android app, using the actual Android Google maps api as opposed to using the JavaScript Google maps api inside a WebView ?

Answer (score 1):

MapView inside Activty:  I think this is the best option, considering all of the classes you have access to (`ItemizedOverlay,Overlay,OverlayItem`).  It provides a great framework to use with `MapActivity`.  If you're using a full screen map, or a large map, or are doing things with more than 10 or so waypoints, I would use a mapview.

Javascript MapView - I would use this for a smaller-sized map (quarter screen) or anything with one or two waypoints.  Keep in mind this is a lighter-weight wrapper over MapView, so heavy processing for multiple overlays may take longer, because you'll have to re-execute your JS code and refresh the WebView.

Overall, IMHO, I would use a MapView inside of a `MapActivity` because it provides a beefier interface, as well as access to some of the better classes.

Good luck!

Comment: What extra features does the the Java Android Google Map libraries have that are lacking in the Google Maps JavaScript API (V3) ?

Comment: From what I understand, javascript provides no way to use `ItemizedOverlay`,`OverlayItem`, or `Overlay` itself.  They _do_ have their own class called `Marker`.  On the other hand, the JS interface allows you to change markers based on zoom level, as well as many other features like databases. Here is a link that gives some tips on how to make the Javascript map work for you: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/
However, I am using threads to continuously update the position of my markers as well as rotate the map.  Using a WebView map simply wouldn't hold up to these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a realated thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445923/google-maps-android-api-v2-vs-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)
the aim of this one is to found which one correspond best to my needs for my next app.
I have started to analyse some of the basic features of javascript v3 and android v2.